# Предлагаю добавить "Рекомендовать удаление" в очереди проверок "Первые вопросы"

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок, ответы

В очередях проверок заметил такой момент: в очереди "Запоздалые ответы" при проверке есть возможность выбрать пункт "Рекомендовать удаление" и внутри масса причин, которые можно выбрать; при этом в очереди "Первые ответы" есть возможность только оставить комментарий о том, что ответ непонятен или требует дополнительной информации. Хотя в последней очереди зачастую встречаются те ответы, которые хотелось бы как раз рекомендовать к удалению ([пример, который мне попался сегодня в этой очереди](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1470306/508294)). Я, конечно, понимаю, что можно поставить тревогу на вопросе и в ней уже указать рекомендацию к удалению, но мне кажется, что пункт "Рекомендовать удаление" в очереди "Первые вопросы" тоже был бы уместен.

Comment: Видимо идея такая, что раз это первый вопрос, то надо помочь ТС сделать его правильным (т.е. обучить ТС), а не удалять (т.е. прогонять ТС).

Comment: @Kromster, возможно. Но тогда можно расширить перечень стандартных комментариев в пункте "Оставить отзыв", а то он немного куцый, честно говоря:/

Comment: При проверке вопросов (не только в запоздалых вопросах, но и в очереди сообщений низкого качества) в принципе нет опции удалить. Если вопрос низкокачественный (требует доработки), то его нужно закрыть, а не сразу сносить. По поводу вариантов в пункте оставить отзыв - никто вам не мешает просто оставить свой комментарий под вопросом.